docker-compose golang cant connect to mariadb
version: "3"

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: ../
    links:
      - mariadb
    expose:
      - 6969
    ports:
      - "6969:6969"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11.8
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=myappdb
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./datadir:/var/lib/mysql
      - ../schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


when running "docker-compose up --build" I get "lookup mariadb on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving" error on golang sql driver when connecting like this:
root:password@tcp(mariadb:3306)/myappdb?parseTime=true
whats the issue in my config? thanks in advance.

the issue was not specifying "networks" for mariadb.
